# PHP URL link variable

Tags: php, dynamic, hyperlink

I have the following problem.

I do a while mysql_fetch_arry function to get values from a table.

And I want at each line, in the end, a text field (amount) and a button (add).

Code looks like this:

```
<?php while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )): ?>
<td id="articlenr" class="width1left"><a href="www.google.de\<?php echo $info['articlenr'] ?>"><?php echo $info['articlenr'] ?> </a></td>
<td class="width2center"><?php echo $info['stock']. " / " .$info['minstock'] ?></td>
<?php endwhile ?>
```

The second line is for article details, what is working.

How can I make a function which does an onclick Event on the button and the textfield on each line?

on button click should happen:

1. get value from textfield "amount" (this line) and Articlenr (this line)
2. build a link which is "....\add.php?article=articlenr(from this line)&ammount=ammount(from this line)
3. open a new window

Comment: IDs have to be unique, you can't use the same `id="articlenr"` each time.

Comment: Don't use backslashes in those urls. Even if you get the whole thing to work, they'll cause strange characters and sometimes they may also break quotes... Just a note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )): ?>
<td class="width1left"><a href="www.google.de\<?php echo $info['articlenr'] ?>"><?php echo $info['articlenr'] ?> </a></td>
<td class="width2center"><?php echo $info['stock']. " / " .$info['minstock'] ?></td>
<td><input type="text" id="amount<?php echo $info['articlenr'] >?"></td>
<td><input typ="button" value="add" onclick="openWindow('<?php echo $info['articlenr'] ?>');"></td>
<?php endwhile ?>

<script>
function openWindow(articlenr) {
    var amount = document.getElementById('amount'+articlenr).value;
    var url = ".../add.php?article="+articlenr+"&ammount="+amount;
    window.open(url);
}
</script>
```

Comment: its not working :( just nothing happens when click the button.

Comment: i have the script tried in <head> and a extrnal .js but it doesnt work anyway

Comment: Open the Developer Tools or Firebug and go to the console tab.

Comment: 13:12:27.889 SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal

Comment: and Firebug gives:

SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal
 

openWindow(206N874735);

Comment: function openWindow(articlenr) {

Comment: I suspect you have something before it that isn't terminated properly. There's no numeric literal on that line.

Comment: it is, it gets it from the Input, i looked via "inspect object".
its encoded to:
<input type="button" onclick="openWindow(206N874735);" value="add"></input>

Isnt there something about Java, that it cant begin with a number? (i think i heard something like this...)

Comment: this is php:
<td><input type="button" value="add" onclick="openWindow(<?php echo $info['articlenr'] ?>);"></td>

Comment: I assumed `articlenr` was a number, not a string. I've updated the answer to put quotes around it in the `onclick` attribute.

Comment: Now i get an error:
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
 

var amount = document.getElementById('amount'+articlenr).value;

Comment: Sorry, `$articlenr` should have been `$info['articlenr']`.

Comment: Looks like you already fixed that in the `onclick`, it also needed to be fixed in `id="article<?php echo $articlenr ?>`"`

Comment: O MY GOD...im so stupid... sorry...i had a space between the ?> and the ".

Thank you very much for you help with this, sir!